# PHP - Array Merge - Removing Array Keys from an Array before Merging

Tags: php

Below is the `print_r($result)` result of an `$result = array_merge(array($id => $value), array($user => $value), array("Information" => $value))` variable in a piece of PHP code:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [user] => 1 
    [Information] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 'John' ) 
                            [1] => Array ( [family] => 'Goldenberg' ) 
                            [2] => Array ( [age] => '21' )))
```

How to remove the array keys from the `"Information" => $value` array in PHP to make the output like below:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [user] => 1 
    [Information] => Array ([name] => 'John' 
                            [family] => 'Goldenberg' 
                            [age] => '21'))
```

Is there any specific function in PHP to complete this task? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please correct the statement in the `array_merge()`, it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Information" array is a multidimensional one, having some arrays as the elements, in which there are some "key-value" pairs as "data". You may use the following to reinsert the "data" in the desirable way:

```
<?php
$info = array( array('name'=>'John'), array('family' => 'Goldenberg'), array('age' => 21));
$out = array();
foreach($info as $arr)
    foreach($arr as $key => $val)
        $out[$key] = $val;
print_r($out);
?>
```